# Operator | cannot be applied to two "PFLoginFields" operands Swift

Tags: ios, swift

here is the code

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) { 
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    if (PFUser.currentUser() == nil) {
        self.LogInViewController.fields = PFLogInFields.SignUpButton | PFLogInFields.PasswordForgotten | PFLogInFields.DismissButton
    }
}
```

King Regards

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replace

```
PFLogInFields.SignUpButton | PFLogInFields.PasswordForgotten |  PFLogInFields.DismissButton
```

with

```
[.SignUpButton, .PasswordForgotten, .DismissButton]
```

Comment: Can you add a little explanation?

Comment: Apple made this change to many options in Swift 2 replacing or-ing together options to using an array of options. It makes the case of no option easier and consistent: `[]`.